# Object.create() with Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

i been playing with inheratance in javascript and right now i been playing with Object.create, and i got this scenerio

```
var Car = function() {
  this.constructor = function(value) {
    this._val = value;
    this.accelerate = false;
  };
};

Car.prototype.accelerate = function() {
  this.accelerate = true;
};

Car.prototype.getVal = function() {
  return this._val;
};

var myCar = Object.create(Car);
```

if i try myCar.getVal() don't work, i get an error saying that the method don't exist in that object? why this happens? and finally which is the right way to use Object.create()?

best regards.

Comment: there's no prototypejs there that I can see

Comment: you will also have problems with their being both a method (in the prototype) called `accelerate` and a property with the same name.

Comment: @Alnitak: Good points both. I fixed the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never call either `Car` or the function you're assigning to `this.constructor` within `Car`, so the code in it never runs, and you don't see `_val` or `accelerate` on any objects.

The way you've done it isn't usually how you do constructors. The usual thing is for `Car` to *be* the constructor, e.g.:

```
var Car = function(value) {  // Added parameter, otherwise `value` was coming from nowhere
  this._val = value;
  this.accelerating = false; // Side note: Changed so it doesn't conflict with the method
};
```

And of course, with constructor functions, you don't need to use `Object.create`. Just call the function via `new`:

```
var myCar = new Car(42);
```

That is roughly equivalent to this:

```
var myCar = Object.create(Car.prototype);
Car.call(myCar, 42);
```

Normally when you're using `Object.create`, you don't have constructor functions so much as builders, like this:

```
var carProto = {
  accelerate: function() {
    this.accelerating = true; // Side note: Changed so it doesn't conflict with the method
  },
  getVal: function() {
    return this._val;
  }
};

function Car(value) {
  var c = Object.create(carProto);
  c._val = value;
  return c;
}

var myCar = Car(42);
```

Comment: @RommelCastro: If you're interested in inheritance in JavaScript, you may be interested in my [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/) script -- possibly to use it, or possibly just to see the [comparison of `Lineage` vs. straight JavaScript](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/wiki/ComparisonWithPlainJavaScript), which demonstrates some things around how you handle inheritance, supercalls, etc.